# else statement in "if in" function in python does not work

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I want to use "if in" to find "1" or "2" inside a number of the user input,
the function works, but when i add the "else" function, code fails, and i dont know why,help please.

```
 a = input("Please enter a number: ")
if "1" in a:
 print("1")
elif "2" in a:
      print("2")
      else:
          print("1 or 2 not found")
```

Comment: How does the code fail? And did you format the code like you pasted it here?

Comment: fix your indentation; that will fix your issue

Comment: i get " invalid syntax" error.

Comment: Thanks ! it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python uses formatting (indentation) to determine how the code runs. Can you try this?

```
a = input("Please enter a number: ")
if "1" in a:
 print("1")
elif "2" in a:
  print("2")
else:
  print("1 or 2 not found")
```

Comment: In that case give it a plus and accept it as an answer so the next person with this problem knows what to do ;)

Comment: i tried to add the another elif with "and option" (&&), for a case that both "1" & "2" are inside the number, is there a way to do that ?

Comment: it work ok, but apperantly the and function must be the first if statement.